# How to connect IOS to Android using WIFI?

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, wifi, communication

I need send information between Android and IOS through WIFI.

Exist any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just use a simple TCP Socket connection.

On Android, use the [`Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) class, on iOS use a method like explained [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server).

Comment: What can i do if i dont have the IPs because are dynamically assigned by the router?. I need something like Universal Plug and Play. Any idea?

Comment: use zeroconf aka Bonjour

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use UPnP (Universal Plug and Play) for an easy connection. In UPnP architecture standard, you can create for example, an UPnP Server in the Android, and UPnP client in IOS.
Here you have the Android implementation: [UPnP in Android](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/)
Here you have the IOS implementation: [UPnP in IOS](https://code.google.com/p/upnpx/)

Answer (score 1):

here: [UPnP Android server](http://4thline.org/projects/download/)

you can find a server UPnP android sample. In the cling-distribution-2.0-alpha3 file. In the folder \demo\android\light\src

And you can play with that using the desktop client: cling-mediarenderer-2.0-alpha3-standalone